# How to keep the endpoint URL same when deploying the microservice on different servers

Tags: endpoint

I am working on some microservices which gets called by some other applications. Sometimes I have to move the microservices to different servers and every time I do it, I have to inform other teams and ask them to update there applications to call the new endpoints which is on new server.
Is there a way to keep the URLs same for the consumers so that I can deploy the service anywhere and they dont have to update the endpoint from there end every time.

Thank you,
JW

Answer (score 1):

If you change the server, the URL gets changed.

Directly exposing the individual URLs of microservices is not a good idea.

If you are using the Kubernetes, you can connect to the microservice through the service name of the microservice if that microservice is also part of that Kubernetes cluster.

like HTTP:://serivice-name-8080/customer/{id}

You can use API gateway, which will be the single point of contact to connect your microservices. In this case, you don't need to change the relative URL.

like HTTP:://{API-GATEWAY}/customer/{id}